# Keycloak exception "Cannot access delegate without a transaction"

Tags: java, keycloak

Context: **Keycloak 1.9.1.Final and newer versions**

Hi,

I have created a custom user federation provider which is a simple variation of the Keycloak's classpath property federation provider example. Instead of reading the usernames in a property file, I fetch then from an external web service.

My trouble is that sometimes I get the following exception when trying to authenticate with a test user:

```
Failed authentication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access delegate without a transaction
  at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getDelegate(UserCacheSession.java:78)
  at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.addUser(UserCacheSession.java:442)
  at com.example.keycloak.MyFederationProvider.getUserModel(MyFederationProvider.java:324)
  at com.example.keycloak.MyFederationProvider.getUserByUsername(MyFederationProvider.java:206)
  at org.keycloak.models.UserFederationManager.getUserByUsername(UserFederationManager.java:237)
  at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:273)
  at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.validateUserAndPassword(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:127)
  at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.validateForm(UsernamePasswordForm.java:56)
  at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.action(UsernamePasswordForm.java:49)
  at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:84)
  at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:759)
  at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:359)
  at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:341)
  at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:386)
  ...
```

I can't figure out why this exception occures. I looked at the `org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession` class and I could see that the exception is thrown when `transactionActive` variable is false, but I don't understand under what conditions it is set to false.

I tried forcing a transaction with `KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction()` method or by adding `begin()` and `commit()` arround the `addUser()` call, but it didn't solved the issue (I got a new error which informs that transaction is already active).

Did you already experienced this exception and know how to avoid it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that if I force a realm and user cache reset in "Realm Settings" and I immediately restart Keycloak, then the login works once. If I log in with another login, the exception occurres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I could find my error (or at least a workarround).

The `getInstance()` method of my user federation provider was always returning the same object (a singleton). I updated it in order to make it create a new provider every time the method is called.

This seems to solve the issue.